# Automatic git deployment from Github to a small Windows server

Tags: git, deployment, github

We're a small 5 person team that are developing a JSF 2.1 website as a two month project. We want to use this project to learn Git/Github since it seems it has a very wide usage, and knowing how to use it will be useful when going into work.

I have a Windows HTPC at home that is always on, and I'd like to use this as a web server during the project. I've been Googling around on how to set up automatic deployment so that the web server grabs the newest master version as the current website. But most results seem to be on a Linux based server. Am I able to implement some kind of [Git Hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)? Most examples of this have been bash scripts. I am no experienced with batch scripts.

Short question: I want to automatically pull the newest version from Github to a Windows server. Any pointers on how to manage this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very alpha, but I open sourced a simplistic .net web app that does what you want.

It can receive http POSTs (eg. from github post-receive hook), and do a git pull + run optional pre and post deploy scripts if you want.

https://github.com/benjamine/gitdeployhub

Comment: I'll definitively look into this. Thanks!

Comment: cool don't hesitate in report issues or send pull requests if you wish. as I'm still working on it, the documention is pretty scarce, so let me know if you have questions. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you need is a post-commit hook that invokes a shell script to login to the server and deploy the newest version.